# How to build a model from scratch in FastAI.jl

Tags: julia, fast-ai, flux.jl

I would like to define my own model in FastAI.jl rather than use one of the pre-trained ones (of which it looks like there is only one or two available [per the source code](https://github.com/FluxML/FastAI.jl/tree/master/src/models)). I was reading through [the docs](https://fluxml.ai/FastAI.jl/dev/docs/introduction.md.html) and it seems to reference a pre-trained resent model everywhere a model is required and I don't see a section about defining my own models. Is it possible to do this in FastAI.jl and if so, how?